# Dell 7490 system does not suspend correctly with Ubuntu 18 with any kernel

Tags: kernel, suspend, dell

My problem is that suspend often does not work correctly in my Dell Latitude 7490 laptop. The OS seems to think that the computer went to suspend, but it does not, the power light keeps on and it consumes power like normal running.

```
debashishc@DebashishC-ublp:~$ uname -a
Linux DebashishC-ublp 5.0.13-050013-generic #201905051330 SMP Sun May 
5 13:32:41 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have tried other kernels as well including 4.14, but with little success. I also have the following in my '/etc/default/grub' even though I do not have an NVidia graphics card.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_sleep=nonvs nouveau.modeset=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

This does load the kernel parameters correctly.

```
cat /proc/cmdline 
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.0.13-050013-generic root=UUID=9250662f- 
23aa-4559-b05f-327fd41d8040 ro acpi_sleep=nonvs nouveau.modeset=0
```

Please help.

Comment: What leads you to believe: *"The OS seems to think that the computer went to suspend"*? Is there a system log you were looking at you can share?

Comment: Do you have an NVMe M.2 SSD card?

Comment: How do I check if I have an NVMe M.2 SSD card?

Comment: This Q&A answers that: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008875/how-can-i-check-the-nvme-specs

Comment: I don't have NVMe SSD as I cannot see it with the lsblk command.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. Installing 'tlp , recommended by some people does not work stable. The behaviour is stochastic: sometimes works, most of the time not. Even sometimes ends up in CPU failure (Blinking lights of Dell 7490). Dell support claims it is an Ubuntu 18.04 problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Dell Latitude 7490 with Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2) doesn't seems to be stable, especially for suspend, with the HWE kernel on Ubuntu 18.04.2 and up.

Try installing an earlier Ubuntu 18.04 version. You can find the older Ubuntu releases [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/).