# How to determine from command line if NVMe slot is gen 3 or gen 4?

Tags: command-line, nvme

The goal is to determine if a Gen-4 NVMe is supported (Gen-4 bandwidth) in a  [Dell 3090 micro i3 10105T](https://M.2%202280,%202%20TB,%20PCIe%20NVMe%20Gen4%20x4,%20Class%2040%20SSD) (Comet Lake).

- NVMe slot is vacant
- SATA Drive outfitted with OSX and Ubuntu

How to determine from command line if NVMe slot is gen 3 or gen 4?  It is not clear to me that **[lsblk](https://askubuntu.com/a/1008891/545291)** will reveal the NVMe specs.

The [link](https://M.2%202280,%202%20TB,%20PCIe%20NVMe%20Gen4%20x4,%20Class%2040%20SSD)  does indicate a single instance of NVME-4:

[image]

It would preferable to confirm NVME-4 compatibility from the command line: before buying the drive.  [Reddit seems to indicate 10th gen CPUs do not support NVME-4?](https://www.reddit.com/r/intel/comments/mvqtzc/10th_gen_processors_and_m2_nvme_pcie_gen_4/)

Answer (score 8):

One way to determinate the generation of a slot where a device is attached is by its bandwidth.

```
+------------------+------------------------------------+
| PCI Express Gen  | Bandwidth per line (x4 slot width) |
+------------------+------------------------------------+
| PCIe Gen1        |  2 GT/s                            |
| PCIe Gen2        |  4 GT/s                            |
| PCIe Gen3        |  8 GT/s                            |
| PCIe Gen4        | 16 GT/s                            |
+------------------+------------------------------------+
```

First we need to identify at which PCIe slot the device is attached.

```bash
$ lspci | grep -i nvme
```

```
08:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller 980
```

Then we can get a detailed information about the slot and the device (and filter the necessary lines) by the following commands. Note using `sudo` is needed to get the verbose information.

**1.** Get the generation of the attached device.

```bash
$ sudo lspci -vv -s 08:00.0 | grep -w LnkCap
```

```
LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x4, ASPM L1, Exit Latency L1 <64us
```

Here we can see the device supports up to **8 GT/s** thence it is **Gen3**.

**2.** Get the generation of the PCIe itself.

```bash
$ sudo lspci -vv -s 08 | grep -w LnkCap
```

```
LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 16GT/s, Width x16, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 16GT/s, Width x16, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
```

Here we can see the slot supports up to **16 GT/s** thence it is **Gen4**.

Comment: I get 02:00.0 from the `lspci | grep -i nvme`. But the last command: `sudo lspci -vv -s 02 | grep -w LnkCap` results in no output.

Comment: Hello, @user68186. I was thinking the key LnkCap is a kind of a standard property for such device, but probably it is hardware vendor specific. You could try with something like `sudo lspci -vv -s 02 | grep -i 'layer\|lnkctl\|gt/s'` or you can just use `sudo lspci -vv -s 02`  and analyse the output by yourself.